# Swift questions are missing syntax highlighting

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting, languages

I saw Swift got some syntax highlighting then when you changed the tag to `swift` it lost it again!

Answer (score 4):

Language was set to "none"; I changed it to "default", which should be fine for anything vaguely C-like.

Comment: Though on that note, if we wanted Swift itself to be officially supported, wouldn't we have to badger the Google Code Prettify guys as per http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/189840 ?

Comment: Yes, you would @Dennis. If "vaguely C-like" isn't good enough for you, that is.